# What are the keywords '%type' and '%token' used for in C?

Tags: c, syntax, keyword

While I was digging into [OpenNTPD](http://openntpd.org/) source code files, I noticed new keywords and syntaxs that I've never seen in any C code before such as `}%`, `%%`, `%type` and `%token` in a file named [parse.y](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.sbin/ntpd/parse.y?rev=1.49;content-type=text/plain):

```
%{
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

...

%}

%token  LISTEN ON
%token  SERVER SERVERS SENSOR CORRECTION RTABLE REFID WEIGHT
%token  ERROR
%token  <v.string>      STRING
%token  <v.number>

....

grammar     : /* empty */
        | grammar '\n'
        | grammar main '\n'
        | grammar error '\n'        { file->errors++; }
        ;

main        : LISTEN ON address listen_opts {
            struct listen_addr  *la;
            struct ntp_addr     *h, *next;

            if ($3->a)
...
```

Most of the file's contents have the usual C syntax except these keywords. Does someone know what these keywords are and what they are used for?

Comment: This is a [Yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) parser definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that this is [Yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) code (i.e. the definition of a [grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar)), not plain C. This is a notation similar to [BNF](http://written%20in%20a%20notation%20similar%20to%20BNF.).

Comment: Of course, Yacc is in some sense a superset of C. (Or at least, typically contains much valid C code.)

Answer (score 0):

And if you look at `*.l` files, you might also see a lot of C code, mixed with `%%`, `%x`, `%s`, `%option` etc. Then it's a lexer input file, which often is accompanied by a yacc `*.y` file.